# Docker: When trying to run docker run hello-world getting - Forbidden

Tags: windows-7, docker, firewall

This is windows 7 machine, Installed docker using docker toolbox version 1.8.2

I am behind corporate firewall.

Initially I was not able to even start the machine so I added two new environment variables: http_proxy, https_proxy and I was able to bring up the default machine

Now when I run, I get:

```
XXXXXX@CCCCCCC MINGW64 ~  
$ docker run hello-world
An error occurred trying to connect: Post https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.20/containers/create: Forbidden
```

Please help.

ps: The other issues on stackoverflow are related to MAC and hence not applicable to me, so admins please don't waste my time in closing this item unnecessarily.

Answer (score 9):

From the looks of it, the `docker` command-line tool is trying to use your proxy server to connect to the Docker daemon running inside your VM.

Since your host and your Docker VM are running in the same network, you probably won't need the proxy server for talking to the Docker daemon. Try setting the `no_proxy` environment variable in order to instruct the Docker client to not use the proxy server for that particular address:

```
export no_proxy=$(docker-machine ip <insert-vm-name-here>)
```

Comment: After setting no_proxy, now getting 

`$ docker run hello-world Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: dial tcp XX.XX.XX.XXX:443: connection refused`

Comment: Adding the NO_PROXY environment variable made it possible for the Docker Client to talk to the Docker Server running in the VM. However, the Docker Server now wants to communicate with the external repository to download the hello-world container. My guess is that you need to add the proxy setting inside your Docker Server.

There's a nice article explaining the procedure here:

http://mflo.io/2015/08/13/docker-machine-behind-proxy/

Once you've added proxy settings and restarted the VM, you should be able to proceed.

Comment: This answer solved a similar problem for me: I'm using docker on a Linux system, and got the "Forbidden" error when trying to do command slike `docker ps`.

Comment: I was having the same problem on my **windows 7 64 bits** behind a company proxy and your solution just worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

So you probably have an issue with the env variables for your `docker-machine`  Looks like it can't find the right certs under ${HOME}/.docker

Try setting your environment:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)
```

If nothing works remove your default docker-machine

```
docker-machine rm default
```

and re-created it.

```
docker-machine create default
```

Comment: After removed and trying to create the the machine getting:

    `Error creating machine: --url option is required when no driver is selected:


    You will want to check the provider to make sure the machine and associated resources were properly removed.`

Comment: try docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default the list of drivers you can find here: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/

Answer (score 2):

For me the below info from :https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/ solved the issue.

Note:Some users reported problems connecting to Docker Hub on Docker for Windows stable version. This would manifest as an error when trying to run docker commands that pull images from Docker Hub that are not already downloaded, such as a first time run of docker run hello-world. If you encounter this, reset the DNS server to use the Google DNS fixed address: 8.8.8.8.

Comment: This worked for me on Mac OS X El Capitan. Went to *System Preferences > Network > Advanced > DNS* and added DNS server 8.8.8.8. After that, I restarted Docker for Mac and ran `docker run hello-world` successfully.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have set 

`export http_proxy="......."`

in my bash_profile. Comment it out seems to solve the problem for Docker.

I tried @helmbert's suggestion, but simply `export no_proxy...` did not work for me.

Note: I'm running Docker Toolbox 1.12.1 on OsX 10.10

Answer (score 1):

I use a proxy and I had the error returned when I followed the docker tutorial https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/, after executing the following:

```
docker-machine env <VM name>
eval $(docker-machine env <VM name>)
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml <app name>
```

I solved it using:

```
docker-machine env --no-proxy <VM name>
```

instead of:

```
docker-machine env <VM name>
```